# Realm Swift Bundle Data

Tags: swift, database, realm, bundle, data-migration

I converted a csv file to a realm file and I want to use it in my app.
This is my code atm:

```
func inLibrarayFolder(fileName: String) -> URL {
    return URL(fileURLWithPath: NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.libraryDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0], isDirectory: true)
        .appendingPathComponent(fileName)
}


func copyPreBundleDataCompeletely() {
    let mainRealmUrl = inLibrarayFolder(fileName: "main.realm")
    let bundleUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "treesFull", withExtension: "realm")!
    
    //After launch after fresh install (if main.realm never created)
    if (!FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: mainRealmUrl.path)){
        //copy bundled data into writable location compeletely
        try! FileManager.default.copyItem(
            at: bundleUrl, to: mainRealmUrl)
        print(mainRealmUrl)
    }
}
```

During the first launch, it creates the new file, but the file is a bit different from the original:

[original db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Nd5m.png)
[copied db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPyeF.png)

the Tree object:

```
class Tree: Object {
    @objc dynamic var id: Int32 = 0
    @objc dynamic var br = ""
    @objc dynamic var nm1 = ""
    @objc dynamic var nm2 = ""
    @objc dynamic var nm3 = ""
    @objc dynamic var longitude = 0.0
    @objc dynamic var latitude = 0.0
 
//    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
//        return "id"
//    }
    
}
```

It looks like I have 2 databeses in the new file, how can I access the second one with the data or how can I copy the file properly?

Also, whats gonna happen when I make the id to a primary key? Obviously I dont have a parameter like that in the original downloaded file, so I guess I will need to migrate the data somehow...

Comment: When you say you *converted a csv file*, can you elaborate a bit as there isn't a direct 'convert' option as Realm isn't an ASCII flat file? Did you mean Import? Looking at your screen shot, in the Models, those fields are created based on the Tree Realm object in your app. I think you've created a model *londonTrees* model that's it's own separate object. As a side node, please include images IN the question as links can break over time and if it does, future readers won't be able to see it.

Comment: I used the "Create Realm from CSV" function in RealmStudio.

Comment: Ok. The import file needs to be in a very specific format. The name of the file needs to exactly match the name of your model. In this case it would need to be `Tree.csv`. Then the first line of the file needs to match your field names, comma separated 'id,br,nm1...`.  I would suggest creating a very small test file to import with 3-4 lines to get it working. Then, once you mastered that then import the big file.

Comment: you were right about the file name, thanks!

Comment: My pleasure. This question has come up a few times before so I added that comemnt a formal answer so future readers can find it. If it solved the issue, please accept it so it can help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to importing, the file being imported has to be in a very specific format along with a specific file name

Your Realm object name is *Tree*, so the imported file name needs to match

```
Tree.csv
```

along with that the first line of the file needs to match the classes property names, comma separated

```
id,br,nm1...
```

I would suggest creating a very small test file to import with 3-4 lines to get it working. Then, once you mastered that then import the big file.