# How to import data into Realm from XLSX file & how to filter data from an array based on an object's value

Tags: swift, uitableview, filter, import, realm

I have an excel database of questions which I am trying to load into Realm. From Realm I would like to filter the questions based on their subject & then load them into a tableView.

I have:

1. Realm Browser Downloaded
2. Realm added to my swift file

Would very much appreciate any advice you could give on this process.

[image]

Comment: Show your code, particularly your model. What have you tried?

Comment: You can't import an .xls file into Realm Studio (please update from Realm Browser as it's depreciated). You'll need to either save it as a txt file in the proper format and then import, or write code to import the data from the .xls file and store it in Realm. See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61463208/realm-swift-bundle-data/61524998#61524998) for importing tip. Also, please limit questions to one question per question or else it will likely be closed. [Filtering](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#filtering) data is covered in the Getting Started Guide