# Realm 5.0.1 file shows up empty in Xcode 11.4

Tags: xcode, realm

I’m using Realm 5.0.1 in Xcode 11.4.
My realm file is showing up empty (which it isn't):

Here is the class:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Place4: Object {
    @objc dynamic var api:String?
    @objc dynamic var apiCounty:String?
... 
    @objc dynamic var utmY:String?
    @objc dynamic var propDepth:String?
    
}
```

All fields are optional String. Here is the code that accesses the realm file:

```
        static let config = Realm.Configuration(fileURL: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Place4", withExtension: "realm"), inMemoryIdentifier: nil, syncConfiguration: nil, encryptionKey: nil, readOnly: true, schemaVersion: 0, migrationBlock: nil, deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded: false, shouldCompactOnLaunch: nil, objectTypes: nil)

let realm = try! Realm(configuration: config)
let what =  realm.objects(Place4.self)
 print("19c what.count: \(what.count)")
```

output:

```
19c what.count: 0
```

I was able to open the file in Realm Studio using the path obtained as follows:

```
// debug
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Place4", ofType: "realm")
print("89q \(String(describing: path?.description))")
```

OK I simplified the config. It's static because it's in a separate utility class. I have used this code successfully before on other bundled realm files. There's something about these data it doesn't like, like the fact that all properties/fields are optional.

```
 static let config = Realm.Configuration(fileURL: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Place4", withExtension: "realm"))
 let realm = try! Realm(configuration:config)
 places = realm.objects(Place4.self)
 print(places?.count)  // outputs 0 incorrectly
```

Comment: That code looks fairly correct. So the issue is most likely the file or path you're trying to read. Doing some basic troubleshooting is a good idea before posting so we can eliminate some variables. For example, I would break out the file url path to be `let path = Bundle.main....` and then `print(path)` to ensure it's valid.

Comment: Well the path looks good:

Comment: There's really not enough troubleshooting presented in the question to be much help. Not sure why you're using `.url` in one place and `.path` in another. Also not sure why you have all this `inMemoryIdentifier: nil, syncConfiguration: nil...` in your Realm.Configuration setup. Sometimes simpler is better; try the code [here](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#configuring-a-realm). Why is config static `static let config`? Also, is your Realm stored in your app bundle - like a pre-populated Realm you're distributing with your app?

Comment: My headers have commas e.g. 'API,C,10". That could be a problem? And they're in double quotes.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what that means. *headers*? What is API,C,10? That's pretty vague - perhaps you can update and clarify the question to prevent it from being closed?

Comment: I was asking about *your* headers - what's the implementation? Why do you have them and what is their function for your use case. You have a coding error and one aspect of troubleshooting is to eliminate some variables. Per the above questions; did you simplify your code to match what's in the realm guide as mentioned above? Why URL vs path? What is config static? Most importantly, is this a Realm file bundled with your app as part of its assets? If you can provide more information we may be able to nail down the issue.

Comment: OK I finally got places?.count (see code above) to return the correct number of rows. Not sure what I did, but 1) make sure the name of the model object e.g. Place9.swift and the name of the realm file e.g. Place9.realm match; 2)  make sure the property names in the model object and field names in the realm file match. Also creating a realm file from a CSV has not been reliable. Only by hand-entering realm data in Realm Studio  have I been able to read the realm file in swift. In the codewithchris.com Guidebook module, he also ended up hand-entering the data in Realm Studio.

Comment: One more comment: you can't reuse a realm name e.g. Place9.realm. If you run into problems with Place9.realm, start over with Place10.realm.

Comment: We've important HUGE multi-gig files into Realm with no issues. Keeping in mind that with comma delimited files, you have to deal with embedded comma's in the data or else you results will be unreliable. Naming the object and Realm file are unrelated when it comes to a bundle. Take the name of the default realm, which is *default.realm* for example - the objects are not named *default*. HOWEVER, if you're attempting to import data, that's another story - see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61463208/realm-swift-bundle-data/61524998#61524998) for importing.